# Parent model returning an empty array in a one to many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I've set up two models where an Album has a Genre and that Genre has many albums that belong to it.

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :genre_id
  belongs_to :genre
end

class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :albums
end
```

Here's my migration file:

```
class AddGenreIdToAlbum < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :albums, :genre_id, :integer
  end
end
```

In my rails console I can assign a genre to my album as so:

```
album = Album.last
album.genre = Genre.last
```

The problem is that if I query the albums for that genre I get an empty array:

```
genre = Genre.last
genre.albums
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

What do I need to do in order for both models to save accordingly?

Comment: When you create an album are you assigning it to a Genre? Obviously you'd get an empty array if the Album isn't assigned to a Genre. Just checking :)

Comment: Also, can you confirm you have ```t.belongs_to :genre``` or ```t.integer :genre_id``` in your migration?

Comment: And yes the genre I'm assigning it to does exist within the db

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call [`save!`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/save%21) method.

```
album = Album.last
album.genre = Genre.last
album.save!
```

[`association=(associate)` :](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to)

> Assigns the associate object, extracts the primary key, and sets it as the foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove `attr_accessor :genre_id` from `Album` model as its making `genre_id` a *virtual attribute* which means it will **NOT be persisted** in the database. It will only be available till the instance to which it is assigned is in memory. Once the instance is gone, the assigned value is gone. And I am pretty sure you wish to save the `genre_id` in database as I can see the migration for the same in the question and its only logical in this case.

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :genre_id   ## <<== Remove this
  belongs_to :genre
end
```

Of course! as suggested in the other answers, after this make sure that you actually call `save` method to save the association in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
album = Album.last
Genre.last.albums << album
Genre.last.albums
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see above is that the albums do not get associated with the Genre(Genre.last)
Try:

```
genre = Genre.last
genre.albums.build(Album.last))
genre.save
```

There needs to be a record in the db(album record) with a foreign key to that particular Genre, which will not happen unless we specifically ask it to create the association... am I making sense at all?